# sql query to create a new table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table as follows:
table 1

```
temp_id    node_name  variable_1 variable_2 variable_3
1          ab         a          b           y
2          sdd        a          a           a
3          u          a          s           s
```

and another table as follows:
table 2

```
temp_id    node_name  variable_1 variable_2 variable_3
1          ab         as        sb           y
2          sdd        a          a           a
3          u          a          s           s
```

I want to fetch all the records from **table 1 only** where the combination variable_1, variable_2 and variable_3 of table 1 doesnot match with table 2.
for example in table 1 first record has a,b,y (variable_1, variable_2 and variable_3) and it this does not exists in table2.

How can I do that in TSQL?

Comment: What was wrong with the answers provided the first time you asked this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522821/tsql-query-to-create-new-table-from-a-combination-of-two-tables

Comment: Note that in the other version of this question, the `temp_id` and `node_name` are used as join columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear whether there a requirement for an outer join.  I assume that the columns are all NOT NULL qualified; the condition gets much more complex if any of the `variable_X` columns can hold nulls.

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM Table1 AS T1
  JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Temp_ID = T2.Temp_ID AND T1.Node_Name = T2.Node_Name
 WHERE T1.Variable_1 != T2.Variable_1
    OR T1.Variable_2 != T2.Variable_2
    OR T1.Variable_3 != T2.Variable_3;
```

If NULLS are allowed, then you have to write:

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM Table1 AS T1
  JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Temp_ID = T2.Temp_ID AND T1.Node_Name = T2.Node_Name
 WHERE (T1.Variable_1 != T2.Variable_1
        OR (T1.Variable_1 IS NULL AND T2.Variable_1 IS NOT NULL)
        OR (T2.Variable_1 IS NULL AND T1.Variable_1 IS NOT NULL)
       )
    OR (T1.Variable_2 != T2.Variable_2
        OR (T1.Variable_2 IS NULL AND T2.Variable_2 IS NOT NULL)
        OR (T2.Variable_2 IS NULL AND T1.Variable_2 IS NOT NULL)
       )
    OR (T1.Variable_3 != T2.Variable_3
        OR (T1.Variable_3 IS NULL AND T2.Variable_3 IS NOT NULL)
        OR (T2.Variable_3 IS NULL AND T1.Variable_3 IS NOT NULL)
       );
```

Note that this is not the same as:

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM Table1 AS T1
  JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Temp_ID = T2.Temp_ID AND T1.Node_Name = T2.Node_Name
 WHERE NOT (T1.Variable_1 = T2.Variable_1
       AND  T1.Variable_2 = T2.Variable_2
       AND  T1.Variable_3 = T2.Variable_3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 t1, table2 t2 where
t1.temp_id = t2.temp_id and
( t1.var1 != t2.var1 OR t1.var2 != t2.var2 OR t1.var3 != t2.var3)
```

Comment: I tried this but i am sure why it is not working it fetches all the records from table2.

Comment: You should use the JOIN notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 t1
left outer join table2 t2 on t1.temp_id = t2.temp_id 
where  t1.var1 <> t2.var1 OR t1.var2 <> t2.var2 OR t1.var3 <> t2.var3
```

Comment: Why an LOJ?  The question needs a plain inner join.

Comment: @Jonathan All records from Table1 so Left outer join would be perfect.

Comment: @Jonathan. If there is records not on table 2 it will just display null but all rows from table 1 still displays.if you use inner join it will only display the exact records from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me if you want to check the existence against all rows in table2

```
select T1.*
from table1 as T1
where not exists (select *
                  from table2 as T2
                  where T1.variable_1 = T2.variable_1 and
                        T1.variable_2 = T2.variable_2 and
                        T1.variable_3 = T2.variable_3
                 )
```

or you you only want to check against the rows where temp_id is a match.

```
select T1.*
from table1 as T1
  left outer join table2 as T2
    on T1.temp_id = T2.temp_id and
       T1.variable_1 = T2.variable_1 and
       T1.variable_2 = T2.variable_2 and
       T1.variable_3 = T2.variable_3
where T2.temp_id is null
```

With your test data the result is the same:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qt/113272/

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
select * from Table1 T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 T2
on T1.temp_id = T2.temp_id
where WHERE (T1.variable_1 <> T2.variable_1 AND
T1.variable_2 <> T2.variable_2 AND
T1.variable_3 <> T2.variable_3)
```